# I am looking for some words other than "Unemployed" to make my sentences more understandable

Tags: sentence-construction, word-request

Peter (nickname) is in his late forties. We have been friends for years.
He used to be a stay-at-home dad, because he had 3 young daughters. 
(now they have grown up)
He had been doing a few part-time jobs, for example, piano tutor, violin tutor.
He can cook very well, too.

Our cake shop has some full-time job vacancies and I think he may be interested in some of them.

I want to talk to my manager about Peter.
Here is what I am thinking to tell the manager:

> Peter was a stay-at-home dad. He had been unemployed for years.
>   But he was not actually unemployed. He just was not in any full-time employment in the past few years. He had been doing some past time jobs instead.

Since Peter had got some part-time jobs in the past few years,
I don't think the word, unemployed is the good word to be used here.
But I just couldn't think of other better words.

Please also help me rewrite the above sentences if possible.

Comment: Why don't you just tell your manager exactly that, which you wrote in the first paragraph? Seems to be a pretty good explanation of Peter's situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He wasn't really "unemployed".  Being a stay-at-home parent was his job.  (It just didn't pay much moneywise)